# Unhandled Runtime Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js14

I have encountered with the hydration failed error and Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in  error. When I put Link tag before the second framer motion when I remove the Link tag the error disappear how to resolve this error. What can be the steps I can take to resolve this error as I am using NextJS 14?

The below is the code snippet.

```
"use client"

import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import { SocialIcon } from 'react-social-icons'

type Props = {}

function Header({ }: Props) {
    return (
        <header className='sticky top-0 p-4 flex items-start justify-between max-w-7xl mx-auto z-20 xl:items-center'>
            <motion.div initial={{ x: -500, opacity: 0, scale: 0.5 }} animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1, scale: 1 }} transition={{ duration: 1.5, }} className='flex flex-row items-center'>
                {/* Social Icons */}
                <SocialIcon url="https://twitter.com/dikdhungana2" fgColor='gray' bgColor='transparent' target='_blank' />
                <SocialIcon url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/dikshyant-dhungana-22b7331a6/" fgColor='gray' bgColor='transparent' target='_blank' />
                <SocialIcon url="https://github.com/dikshyant3" fgColor='gray' bgColor='transparent' target='_blank' />
            </motion.div>

            <Link href="contact">
                <motion.div initial={{ x: 500, opacity: 0, scale: 0.5 }} animate={{ x: 0, opacity:     1, scale: 1 }} transition={{ duration: 1.5, }} className='flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer'>
                    {/* Email */}
                    <SocialIcon className="cursor-pointer" network='email'
                        fgColor='gray' bgColor='transparent' />
                    <p className='uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400'>Get in Touch</p>


                </motion.div>
            </Link>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

The below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "porfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@react-email/components": "0.0.12",
    "@react-email/tailwind": "0.0.13",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.12",
    "lucide-react": "^0.294.0",
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
    "react-social-icons": "^6.7.0",
    "resend": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.1.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.0.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I just want to navigate to contact page when I am clicking the icon and text div but it does so by showing errors in the webpage